# Are Quartz's configuration parameters externalizable outside of the default properties file?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Quartz has a properties file which it reads configuration information from usually named quartz.properties. I am using Quartz in an already existing Java/Spring application which lets end users specify configuration parameters via the use of a JSON file. I am wondering can I 'elevate' or 'lift' *some* of the parameters Quartz is reading from the quartz.properties configuration file in my application to my JSON configuration file (which is the user's configuration interface) so the user can enter some parameters that can then be passed to Quartz (via or not via) it's own configuration file, the aforementioned quartz.properties file? If so, what would be a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to initialize the scheduler factory with a [Properties-Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html?is-external=true) before creating a Scheduler.

I.e.

```
// implement the method createPropertiesFromJSON().
// It should read your JSON file (i.e. your configuration) and
// transform it to a Properties object.
Properties propertiesFromJson = createPropertiesFromJSON();
StdSchedulerFactory.initialize(propertiesFromJson);
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
```

Comment: Can this only be done programmatically? How would it be done decoratively via Spring?

Comment: I know at least no other way than to do it programmatically.